# How to calculate the power set of $C=\{i,m,p,r,o,p,e,r\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am being asked to get the $|P(C)|$ of $C=\{i,m,p,r,o,p,e,r\}$. I know that the formula is $2$ raised to $n$, but I am not sure if I will count repeating letters once. Should it be $2^6$ or $2^8$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think for simplicity when defining any set, when a repeat happens, since that element already appeared once we can rewrite your set $\{I,M,P,R,O,P,E,R\} = \{I,M,P,R,O,E\}$. It would be different say, if we had $\{I,M,P,R,O,\{P\},E,R\}$ because then $P, \{P\}$ are not the same. So you can use the same trick to get $2^6 = 64$.

Comment: Okay, thank you!